# Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x^{-x}-1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x^{-x}-1}{x}$$

I think we should use L'Hospital rule and the limit becomes

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} -x^{-x}(\log x + 1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\log x + 1}{-x^{x}}= +\infty$$

Is it right?

I've tried to modify the form and not use L'Hospital's rule but without success.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: It's not $\frac00$ to use L'hospital.

Comment: x^x as it approaches 0 will be 1, and ln(x) as x approaches 0 will be negative infinity, however, it is to the negative sign so it will approach positive infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the Hospital's rule: $$\frac{x^{-x}-1}{x}=-\frac{x^x-1}{x\cdot x^x}=-\frac{e^{x\ln{x}}-1}{x\ln{x}}\cdot\ln{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x^x}\rightarrow+\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use $x^{-x}=e^{-x\ln(x)}$ and $e^u\approx 1+u$ for $u$ near $0$. Then the expression becomes $\approx \frac{-x\ln(x)}{x}=-\ln(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use *equivalence*: near $u=0$, $\;\mathrm e^u=1+u+o(u)$, so 
$$\mathrm e^{-x\ln x}-1=-x\ln x+o(-x\ln x),\quad\text{which means  }\;x^{-x}-1\sim_0-x\ln x$$
and finally
$$\frac{x^{-x}-1}{x}\sim_0 -\ln x\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}+\infty$$